# How do you create rawStoreDaemon threads in embedded derby db? What causes the thread leak?

Tags: java, database, multithreading, derby, embedded-database

The code creates embedded derby connections in my implementation of PoolableObjectFactory.

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcProtocol+"database/CacheDB;", user, password);
```

The connections are "destroyed" in `destroyObject` just by calling `.close()`.

It seems to work fine, normally.  However, someone else running the program got several thousand rawStoreDaemon threads.

I can't recreate these extra threads.  Whats worse I can't even seem to make 2 derby.rawStoreDaemon threads.  I have had up to 100 connections and several users at once, but nothing seems to even make a second derby.rawStoreDaemon thread.

My basic question is, what makes these threads?  How come there is ever more than one?

Comment: Really, no one?  Someone view the question, lol.

Comment: I see you also asked your question on the Derby mailing lists, which was a good idea. Sometimes, questions aren't viewed immediately, particularly during the holiday season.

Comment: @Bryan Pendleton Is it safe to just kill these threads?

Comment: I ended up trying: jdbc:derby:database/<dbname>';shutdown=true.  I periodically call this, when no connections are needed.  This will kill the valid rawStoreDaemon thread.  I am hopeful this will stop the thread leak.  good luck, this may not work.